# Checking if any stored procedure on a database modifies a certain column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there a way to write a query that would show me the names of any stored procedure on my database that modifies a certain column? This database at work has over 1300 stored procedures listed under System stored procedures and then two others that are not listed under that. I need to know which one modifies the column "CustomFlag 1".

For some reason every 6 months this column is being cleared out for every entry so my assumption is that a stored procedure is doing this and would like to figure out which one so we can fix it.

This is on SQL Server 2008 using SSMS 2008.

Comment: A quick and dirty way I can think of is to create a script of all sprocs, then load this script into a text editor and then perform a CTRL+F using the column name.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a script of your database schema and do a text search within it for "CustomFlag"

You can script out the entire schema (or just the stored procs) by right-clicking on the database name in Sql Server Management Studio and select Tasks/Generate Scripts

Comment: This seems like it will work. Again I am at home so will test at work when I get there. I did do a quick test on my own Personal SQL database which has almost nothing in it and i think this will work quite well.

Comment: Tried this on the database at work and when generating the scripts it got a few thousand in and one of them threw an error under the status column no pop-up box or anything though and everything after that just did not run.

Comment: Tell it to just script out stored procedures.

Comment: I tried and I get error on the first stored procedure. May be an access issue my DBA limits my access something fierce. I can not even create temp tables.

Comment: You will have to get the DBA to answer this question for you then.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081(v=sql.105).aspx) system view to get all sprocs referencing the column that is of interest to you. Field `definition` of the view returns the SQL text that defines the sproc.

As an example, the following query:

```
SELECT obj.Name SPName, sm.definition SPText
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON sm.object_id = obj.OBJECT_ID
WHERE sm.definition LIKE '%' + '[JobTitle] =' + '%' AND TYPE = 'P'
```

returns all sprocs trying to set field `JobTitle` in the `AdventureWorks2008R2` database:

```
SPName                      SPText
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
uspSearchCandidateResumes   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSearchCandidateResumes] ...etc
```

Comment: This seems like it will work however I am at home and so will test it when i get there. Thanks for the response. I learned a look out of this post that I will likely use in the furture